# I am trying to replace NaN values with mean values

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

i have to replace the s_months and incidents NaN values with the corresponding means in jupyter notebook.
Input data :

```
    Types   c_years     o_periods   s_months    incidents
0   1       1           1           127.0       0.0
1   1       1           2           63.0        0.0
2   1       2           1           1095.0      3.0
3   1       2           2           1095.0      4.0
4   1       3           1           1512.0      6.0
5   1       3           2           3353.0      18.0
6   1       4           1           NaN         NaN
7   1       4           2           2244.0      11.0
14  2       4           1           NaN         NaN
```

I have tried the code below but it does not seem to work and I have tried different variations such as replacing the transform.

```
df.fillna['s_months'] = df.fillna(df.grouby(['types' , 'o_periods']['s_months','incidents']).tranform('mean'),inplace = True)
```

```
                 s_months  incidents
Types o_periods                     
1     1               911          3
      2              1688          8
2     1             26851         36
      2             14440         36
3     1               914          2
      2               862          1
4     1               296          0
      2               889          3
5     1               663          4
      2              1046          6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Types,c_years,o_periods,s_months,incidents
0,1,1,1,127.0,0.0
1,1,1,2,63.0,0.0
2,1,2,1,1095.0,3.0
3,1,2,2,1095.0,4.0
4,1,3,1,1512.0,6.0
5,1,3,2,3353.0,18.0
6,1,4,1,NaN,NaN
7,1,4,2,2244.0,11.0
14,2,4,1,NaN,NaN"""), sep=',')
>>> df
    Types   c_years     o_periods   s_months    incidents
0   1       1           1           127.0       0.0
1   1       1           2           63.0        0.0
2   1       2           1           1095.0      3.0
3   1       2           2           1095.0      4.0
4   1       3           1           1512.0      6.0
5   1       3           2           3353.0      18.0
6   1       4           1           NaN         NaN
7   1       4           2           2244.0      11.0
14  2       4           1           NaN         NaN
```

```py
>>> df[['c_years', 's_months', 'incidents']] = df.groupby(['Types', 'o_periods']).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
>>> df
    Types   c_years     o_periods   s_months    incidents
0   1             1     1           127.000000      0.0
1   1             1     2           63.000000       0.0
2   1             2     1           1095.000000     3.0
3   1             2     2           1095.000000     4.0
4   1             3     1           1512.000000     6.0
5   1             3     2           3353.000000     18.0
6   1             4     1           911.333333      3.0
7   1             4     2           2244.000000     11.0
14  2             4     1           NaN             NaN
```

The last `NaN` is here because it belongs to the last group which contains no value in the columns `s_months` and `incidents` and therefore, no `mean`.

Comment: Types  c_years  o_periods  s_months  incidents
0       1        1          1      127.0        0.0
1       1        1          2       63.0        0.0
2       1        2          1       1095.0        3.0
3       1        2          2       1095.0        4.0
4       1        3          1        1512.0        6.0
5       1        3          2        3353.0       18.0
6       1        4          1          NaN        NaN
7       1        4          2         2244.0       11.0
14      2        4          1          NaN        NaN

Comment: Hello @NicholasKim, I updated my answer with the sample you sent me in the comment. Does this answer helps you ?

Comment: hello, i have done this but my columns types and o_periods of my data disappears. also when i call out of print(df) it does not have the values replaced in the dataframe

Comment: You are right ! Don't worry my friend, the answer has been updated to make then reappear and to replace the values in the `DataFrame`. Is it better ?

Comment: oh my god thank you so much my friend. it is returning me the correct dataframe! would like to ask if this is considered an easy question in the real world?

Comment: In my opinion, it is not so easy as the `mean` has to be computed from each groups, thanks to `Pandas` the answer is not too long to write but the problem stay quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `df['s_months'].fillna(df['s_months'].mean())`
`df['s_months'].mean()` counts mean without `Nan`.

Comment: hello, i have done it but when i print my df it still has Nan values inside. unless i call the fillna independently, the Nans are replaced by correct values

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close, you can try modify it as follows to make it work:

```
df[['s_months','incidents']] = df[['s_months','incidents']].fillna(df.groupby(['Types' , 'o_periods'])[['s_months','incidents']].transform('mean'))
```

**Data Input:**

```
    Types  c_years  o_periods  s_months  incidents
0       1        1          1     127.0        0.0
1       1        1          2      63.0        0.0
2       1        2          1    1095.0        3.0
3       1        2          2    1095.0        4.0
4       1        3          1    1512.0        6.0
5       1        3          2    3353.0       18.0
6       1        4          1       NaN        NaN
7       1        4          2    2244.0       11.0
14      2        4          1       NaN        NaN
```

**Output**

```
    Types  c_years  o_periods     s_months  incidents
0       1        1          1   127.000000        0.0
1       1        1          2    63.000000        0.0
2       1        2          1  1095.000000        3.0
3       1        2          2  1095.000000        4.0
4       1        3          1  1512.000000        6.0
5       1        3          2  3353.000000       18.0
6       1        4          1   911.333333        3.0
7       1        4          2  2244.000000       11.0
14      2        4          1          NaN        NaN
```